# modules cannot load in a new Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, conda, django-3.1

I made 2 projects with django so far and everything smooth.

using python 3.6 and conda env with django 3.1.4

I am following the tutorial to kick off my new project as I did for my previous one : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

Start a new one using "django-admin startproject ngedemocarto"
then used "django startapp sitemanager" it gives me this :

[image]

but suddenly in this project I keep having error when I try to call any app module like "apps.py" or "urls.py"

typical error if I add the app config in settings.py like this :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

resolve in this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfigdjango'; 'sitemanager.apps' is not a package
```

every command like manage.py runserver or manage.py migrate is failing at import because it can't resolve any names like "sitemanager.apps" or "sitemanager.urls"

I checked basic things :

- I have a **init**.py at sitemanager root folder
- urls.py or apps.py exist
- if I use python in cmd at mynewproject folder and try import "sitemanager.apps" , it works. ( no error)

I am in a very basic config just after starting this new project and nothing works ...

I tried to build a new conda env, start a new django project, same thing.

I don't really know where I should look to solve this problem and how to troubleshot it.
It may be an issue with the way python import modules and how I use my python env,
maybe something wrong in sys.path either

My others project keep working, I can use runserver and migrate for exemple.

EDIT & ANSWER:

well,
I was missing a coma for my appconfig
and I didn't create urls.py in sitemanager (was only in the main project)....

Guess I should have take a break, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a comma after 'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig'. The lack of a comma has the effect of django trying to find 'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfigdjango', which does not exist:

before:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

after:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Alternatively, can just add 'sitemanager' instead of 'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig'

Comment: nice catch , and for urls.py, I just didn't create it in sitemanager ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma misding after

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sitemanager.apps.SitemanagerConfig'
```